# On VBA, how do I select the first nonzero cell in a row and shift it to the right one slot?

Tags: vba, loops, row

So here's what I tried, but it doesn't seem to work. What I want to do is really simple, but I'm fairly new to VBA, so I'm struggling. Basically what I want to do is scan the third row of an excel file until I encounter the first nonzero cell. After identifying it, I want to shift that cell by one to the right.

```
Sub MoveFirstNonZeroCell()

  Dim iCell As Range
  Dim R As Range

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Activate
   'Loop through Row 3
    For Each R In Range("3:3")
        If R.Value <> 0 Then
            Set iCell = R
        End If  
    Next
        Range("iCell").Cut Destination:=Range("iCell.Offset(0,1)")

    End With

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help I can get!

Answer (score 0):

For example (if you don't mind overwriting what is to the right)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MoveFirstNonEmpty()
    Dim myAddress As Variant
    myAddress = Evaluate("ADDRESS(3,MATCH(TRUE,Sheet1!3:3<>0,0))")
    If Not IsError(myAddress) Then
        With Range(myAddress)
            .Copy .Offset(, 1)
            .ClearContents
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This simplifies your code and corrects the syntax in `Range("iCell.Offset(0,1)")`.

Note that you should specify what workbook `Sheet1` is in, and also although you have the `With...End With` block, if you don't include the `.` in front of `Range("3:3")`, you're not referring to `Sheet1` but rather have an implicit reference to the `ActiveSheet`.

Finally, an `Exit For` will exit the loop once the first non-zero cell has been found and moved to the right.

```
Sub MoveFirstNonZeroCell()
    Dim R As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each R In .Range("3:3")
            If R.Value <> 0 Then
                R.Cut Destination:=R.Offset(, 1)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next R
    End With

End Sub
```